# aforge.video,ffmpeg on windows 10

Tags: windows, aforge

I have created app that is referencing aforge.video.ffmpeg (with all associated dlls) that is working fine on windows 8, but when I try to run it on Windows 10 it won't work. Does anyone have similar experience? Any advice?